# ActiveRecord model 'type' column of polymorphic association includes namespace of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Question**:

How can I tell ActiveRecord to not include the namespace of the association class while storing/querying the association type column?

**Current state of things:**

Consider the following class definitions:

```
class PageTemplateA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :type_a_pages, :as => :pageable, :class_name => 'TypeAPage', :inverse_of => :pageable
end

##### The following class is implemented through STI.
class TypeAPage < Page
  belongs_to :pageable, :class_name => 'PageTemplateA', :inverse_of => :type_a_page
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

To summarize:

- `TypeAPage` is implemented through STI in the database table, `pages`.
- `TypeAPage` is associated with `PageTemplateA` through a polymorphic association (`pages.pageable_type` is `PageTemplateA` when associated with `PageTemplateA`)

**The change I want to make:**

I want to move all the above models into a new namespace, say, `PagesEngine`, so my definition for `PageTemplateA` looks like:

```
module PagesEngine
  class PageTemplateA < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :type_a_pages, :as => :pageable, :class_name => 'TypeAPage', :inverse_of => :pageable
  end
end
```

This works fine, **except** that ActiveRecord infers the `pageable_type` for `TypeAPage` to be `PagesEngine::PageTemplateA`.

How can I tell ActiveRecord to not include the namespace, and resolve `pageable_type` to `PageTemplateA` instead of `PagesEngine::PageTemplateA`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the model that holds the polymorphic relation, you can set `self.store_full_sti_class = false` or inherit from an abstract model that sets store_full_sti_class to false.

```rb
module PagesEngine
  class Page < Base
    # self.store_full_sti_class = false
    belongs_to :pageable, polymorphic: true
  end

  class TypeAPage < Page
    belongs_to :pageable, 
               class_name: 'PageTemplateA', 
               inverse_of: :type_a_pages
  end
end
```

Explicitly scope the relation (type_as_pages) with the type column (pageable_type) matching the associated model (PagesEngine::PageTemplateA) but without the namespace.

```rb
module PagesEngine
  class PageTemplateA < Base
    has_many :type_a_pages, 
             -> { where(pageable_type: 'PageTemplateA') }, 
             foreign_key: :pageable_id, 
             inverse_of: :pageable
  end
end
```

Finally override belongs_to method and customise Active Record Belongs To Polymorphic Association.

```rb
module PagesEngine
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    self.store_full_sti_class = false

    def self.belongs_to(name, scope = nil, options = {})
      super(name, scope, options).tap do |hash|
        reflection = hash[name.to_s]
        def reflection.association_class
          if polymorphic?
            BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation
          else
            super
          end
        end unless store_full_sti_class
      end
    end
  end

  class BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation < ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation
    def klass
      type = owner[reflection.foreign_type]
      type.presence && PagesEngine.const_get(type)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `self.sti_name` to override the type column name for the respective class:

```
module PagesEngine
  class PageTemplateA < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.sti_name
      "PageTemplateA"
    end
  end
end
```

You might find the following blog article useful: https://lorefnon.me/2014/07/27/optimizing-sti-columns.html

Comment: Thanks for your response , Anthony.

However, in this case, there is no STI implemented on `PageTemplateA`. It is actually on `TypeAPage`.